# What function i could use to perfecting copy paste formula form other workbook sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My copy paste formula from offline workbook sheet

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Report\2017\february\data february\STOCK_REPORT_16_02_" & Year(Date) & ".xls"
    Range("A1:H1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("MGM FEBRUARI.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("STOCK16").Activate
    Range("A2.H2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("STOCK_REPORT_16_02_" & Year(Date) & ".xls").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    UserForm3.Hide
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

by applying " & Year(Date) & " suggested by @Shai Rado I'm able to do the formula without changing the year

but how about month? how to use a proper function for month to be put it on my formula?.....without changing the date only month and year

1. Put function for each; month and year
2. Are there any single function for it

Comment: Try :`MonthName( Month(Date))` to return the month name _(employ with the `&` like you did for the year number)_. Also, I would advise against all the `.Activate` and `.Select` portions of the code, as they will slow your code's execution down significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Format` and a Workbook variable :

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(filename:= _
        "C:\Report\2017\february\data february\STOCK_REPORT_16_" & Format(Date, "mm_yyyy") & ".xls")
    wB.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H1000").Copy
    Workbooks("MGM FEBRUARI.xlsm").Sheets("STOCK16").Range("A2.H2").Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wB.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    UserForm3.Hide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Or with the variable path :

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim DatDate As Date
    Dim wBPath As String
    DatDate = Date

    wBPath = "C:\Report\" & Format(DatDate, "yyyy\MMMM") & "\data " & Format(DatDate, "MMMM") & "\STOCK_REPORT_16_" & Format(DatDate, "mm_yyyy") & ".xls"

    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=wBPath)
    wB.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H1000").Copy
    Workbooks("MGM FEBRUARI.xlsm").Sheets("STOCK16").Range("A2.H2").Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wB.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    UserForm3.Hide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Although I wonder, does OP's file structure (`[...] \february\data february [...]`) suggest that the folder in which the data is found varies depending on the month, so perhaps assigning a `MonthName` variable to substitute into the file path could be useful?

Comment: @Greedo : Indeed, thx for pointing it out, I didn't pay attention to it! I've added that in second code! ;)

Comment: Hi R3uK...i'll try it brb

Comment: @Greedo...thnx i forgot to mention it.

Comment: @R3uK run-time error '9' = Subscript out of range at Workbooks("MGM FEBRUARI.xlsm").Sheets("STOCK16").Range("A2.H2").Paste.........      
mmmm confuse LOL

Comment: @MikoIndra : That means that it didn't find the workbook "MGM FEBRUARI.xlsm" in the opened workbooks, or the sheets "STOCK16" in that workbook. You'll need to change those names to fit your needs! ;)

Comment: @R3uK yeah just found the problem...."STOCK" not "STOK" my bad, try not to copas but type in all the formula, my learning n understanding methode ...got sleepy already LOL btw tnx i'll try also for the folder function brb to update the result